# function for checking incorrect roman numerals python

Tags: python, roman-numerals

I am trying to write a function which takes an input of roman numerals and checking if that is a valid roman numeral. However, the user can input the function in any way that they like. I was wondering how we could check for invalid roman numerals like:
IIII
IIIVMX
and return Error for these values.
The main two errors I want to check for is that:

1. there are no quadruplets like (IIII) or( VVVV)
2. that the roman numerals are ordered from largest to smallest unlike (IIIVMX) but still allow for special roman numerals like (IV and IX).

Also, if your solution involves a dictionary, it must come from this dictionary:

```
values = {
"I": 1,
"V": 5,
"X": 10,
"L": 50,
"C": 100,
"D": 500,
"M": 1000,
```

}

This is my current attempt which works okay, but unfortunately does not check for exceptions like IX or IV

```
def error(input):
     values = {"I": 1,"V": 5,"X": 10,"L": 50,"C": 100,"D": 500,"M": 1000,}
     if len(input)>=4:
         for i,letter in enumerate(input):
            #checking for quadruplets-not sure if it captures all quadruplets
            if input[i]==input[i+3]:
                return False
            #This is where I am having a bit of trouble because I don't know how to code for exceptions like IX or IV
            if values[input[i]]<values[input[i+1]]:
                return False
error('VVVIIII')
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution, in my opinion, is to use a regex like this one `^M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$`. Then your function can look like this :

```py
import re 

reg = "^M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$"

def check_roman(input):
    return re.match(reg, input)
```

Comment: is there a way to not use regular expressions?